# Bootstrap 3: prevent modal inside modal to trigger (hidden.bs.modal) every time

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I have one modal inside another modal and I've managed to make the inner one close without affecting the other. The problem is that when the second modal is closed it triggers the `'hidden.bs.modal'` event for its self and for the first modal.

```
<!-- My Html -->
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open demo modal</button>
<div class="modal" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="false">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                 <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Demo Modal</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>
                    <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#uploadImage" class="btn btn-primary">Upload image</a>
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal" id="uploadImage" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="uploadImage-title" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                     <h4 class="modal-title" id="uploadImage-title">Upload new image</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    Testing Area
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">                
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="btnUploadCancel">Cancel</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Accept</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- My JS-->
$('#btnUploadCancel').click(function () {
    $('#uploadImage').modal('toggle');
});

$(document).on('hidden.bs.modal', '#myModal', function () {
    alert("hello");
});

$(document).on('hidden.bs.modal', '#uploadImage', function () {
    alert("goodbye");
});
```

Here is a [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/wytf57mL/2/) that I made.

The reason for this question is that I need to trigger an action only when the second modal gets hidden and then something else when the first one gets hidden. **Any ideas on how to fix this using the event for each of them???**

**Note:** *The second modal has to be inside the other as they are called as a partial view.*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm guessing that these modal elements are being introduced to the page asynchronously, and that's why you're using a delegated event listener bound to the document rather than binding `hidden.bs.modal` directly to `#myModal` and `#uploadImage` themselves. If this is not the case, and you can get away with binding directly, I'd suggest using this approach to catch the `hidden` event on `#uploadImage` itself, and prevent it from bubbling up the DOM tree using something like `event.stopPropagation();`.

Alternatively, though, you can continue to delegate this handler to the document, and use the `target` property of the `Event` object passed into your handler callback to determine which element was the actual source of the event:

```
$(document).on('hidden.bs.modal', '#myModal', function (event) {
    if (event.target.id == 'uploadImage') {
        // do stuff when the upload dialog is hidden.
    }
    else if (event.target.id == 'myModal') {
        // do stuff when the outer dialog is hidden.
    }
});
```

P.S.: As you may already know, the Bootstrap framework [does not support overlapping modal dialogs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#overlapping-modals-not-supported). Be aware of this as you continue to nest modals within modals, especially concerning dismissal elements initialized via the markup API and `data-dismiss="modal"`.

P.P.S.:

[image: Yo dawg, I heard you like modals, so we put modals in your modals so you can modal while you modal]

Comment: Thank you so much it worked perfectly, it was just what I needed. The only thing that I needed to do was place the code in the main window because when placed in the partial view the second modal inherited all past events.

Answer (score 0):

The second modal html doesn't have to be included in the first modal body. Include only the data-target link and move the second modal outside the first. This way the events will fire as you expect.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open demo modal</button>
<div class="modal" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="false">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                 <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Demo Modal</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>
                    <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#uploadImage" class="btn btn-primary">Upload image</a>
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
<div class="modal" id="uploadImage" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="uploadImage-title" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                     <h4 class="modal-title" id="uploadImage-title">Upload new image</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    Testing Area
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">                
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="btnUploadCancel">Cancel</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Accept</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wytf57mL/3/

Comment: Hi @mihai-alex thanks for the response. I thought of that but I need the second one to be inside the first one as both are called from a partial view. Sorry I wasn't clear about that.